# Unfair coin flipping

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An unfair coin has a 70% chance of being heads. If you flip three of these unfair coins, take out the coins that come up heads and flip the remaining coins until they come up heads. Let Y be the number of trails needed for all the coins to come up heads.

I'm having trouble identifying what type of distribution this would be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about geometric distribution?

Comment: Yes. I know if I'm looking for the heads in n trials, it would be a binomial distribution. How would taking out the heads make it a geometric distribution?

Comment: What are you after? The distribution of $Y$ (I think it is quite complicated) or the expectation of $Y$? It it is the expectation then there are ways to find it without puzzling about the distribution.

Comment: I need to find $$P(Y<=y), y = 1, 2,...$$ and assumed I could find it if I integrated the pdf of it from 1 to y

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for [negative binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) distribution. The expected number $E(Y)$ of coin flipping before head comes up is:

$E(Y) = \frac{1}{1-p}$

which for your unfair coins with $1-p = 0.7$, $E(Y)=1.43$. In your problem, flipping the coins are independent from each other, therefore the expected number of trials before head is observed is equal for all the three coins.

Comment: P would be 0.7, so 1-0.7 would be 0.3 no?

Comment: well negative binomial is a bit tricky. $p$ indicates the chance of success and $1-p$ for failure. Under negative binomial distribution we say how many success before $n$ failures occure. In your problem, first of all $n=1$ and succes is not having head observed, which has 0.3 chance, and failure is observing head which is 0.7.

Comment: But when using the negative binomial we are looking for the r-th success. In this problem we are looking from the number of trials needed to get 3 heads, so why isn't it NegBin(3,0.7)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the distribution of $Y$ then this is not an answer. It only deals about the expectation.

For $n=0,1,\dots$ let $Y_{n}$ denote the number of trails needed by flipping $n$ coins.
Then $Y_{0}\equiv0$.

In your case $p=0.7$, $q=1-p=0.3$ and we want to find $\mathbb{E}Y_{3}$.

Let $X$ be the number of heads that show up in the first trail. Then $Y_{n}$ has under condition $X=i$ the same distribution as $1+Y_{n-i}$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n$. For $n>0$ this leads to:

$$\mathbb{E}Y_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(Y_{n}\mid X=i\right)P\left(X=i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left(1+Y_{n-i}\right)\binom{n}{i}p^{i}q^{n-i}=1+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}Y_{n-i}\binom{n}{i}p^{i}q^{n-i}$$

The equations:$$\mathbb{E}Y_{1}=1+\mathbb{E}Y_{1}\times q$$

$$\mathbb{E}Y_{2}=1+\mathbb{E}Y_{2}\times q^{2}+\mathbb{E}Y_{1}\times2pq$$

$$\mathbb{E}Y_{3}=1+\mathbb{E}Y_{3}\times q^{3}+\mathbb{E}Y_{2}\times3pq^{2}+\mathbb{E}Y_{1}\times3p^{2}q$$
enable you to find a closed form for $\mathbb{E}Y_{3}$ in $p$ and $q$.